# msyql database selection based on if else statement and php variables

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

Having trouble with getting this to work and the syntax - I have never done anything like this before and didn't write some of the original stuff.  I have a url that passes two variables.  I then GET those variables in the page. I then want to select which mysql db I connect to based on one of these variables.

Variable:

```
$account_id=$_GET["reference"];
```

It then chooses which db to connect to:

```
$link = mysql_connect('connect', 'user', 'pass');
if (!$link) {
     die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
 }

if ($item = "A"){
     $db_selected = mysql_select_db('A', $link);
     } elseif ($item = "B") {
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db('B', $link);
    } elseif (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
 }
```

It is consistently choosing item A.  I cannot get it to choose B or give an error. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: When comparing values for logic operations, you must use `>`, `<`, `==`, `===`, `!=`, or `!==`. You are using a single equals sign, which is not for comparison but for assignment. See the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: That ^ and `$item` should be `$account_id`. As it stands, `$item` is undefined. [This will tell you...](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: @ChrisBaker Stealth edit, *now in progress...*

Comment: Would like to give @ChrisBaker more credit for the answer than just an upvote.

Comment: @ChrisBaker I would suggest as OP is also inviting you to put in an answer, just so we can wrap it all up. The assignment instead of comparison was the problem.

Comment: @ChrisBaker - please phrase your comment in the manner of an answer so that I may give you the credit your richly deserve.

Comment: I don't care about internet points :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When comparing values for logic operations, you must use `>`, `<`, `==`, `===`, `!=`, or `!==`. You are using a single equals sign, which is not for comparison but for assignment.

**This is what you are doing**

```
$item = 'b';          // a single equals sign assigns a value
if ($item = 'a') {    // so in this line, we are not comparing but assigning!
    echo 'Item is a'; // this line will always be reached
} else {
    echo 'Item is b'; // this line will NEVER be reached
}
echo 'Item = '.$item; // will ALWAYS read "Item = a"
```

**This is what you meant to do**

```
$item = 'b';           // a single equals sign assigns a value
if ($item == 'a') {    // double-equals compares value, with type juggling
    echo 'Item is a';  
} else {
    echo 'Item is b';  // now this line will be reached, because item != 'a'
}
echo 'Item = '.$item;  // will read "Item = b"


`==`  - value is equal, not necessarily the same type (1 == "1")
`!=`  - value is not equal, may or may not be the same type (2 != "3")
`===` - value is equal AND the same type (1 === 1)
`!==` - value is not the same type, or not the same value (2 !== "2")
```

**Documentation**

- PHP Comparison operators: http://php.net/manual/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Very well written Chris.

Answer (score 1):

use == instead of =

```
if ($item == "A"){
     $db_selected = mysql_select_db('A', $link);
     } elseif ($item == "B") {
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db('B', $link);
    } elseif (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
 }
```